# Algorithm for combining numbers into optimal groups which do not exceed a vector of max values?

Tags: r, grouping, mathematical-optimization

I'm cutting trim molding for my house and have various lengths of trim pieces, and would like to group them optimally for the smallest amount of waste. Basically, I'm trying to optimally group (or pack) the required lengths into the available longer lengths.

I'm a bit stumped on how to approach this and have currently just been doing it by hand, however a mistake ends up causing me to re-work the whole operation. I know some java, but have recently been working exlusively with R, so that's my most familiar language at this point. Are there suggestions for how to approach this?

Is there a better way of doing this than manually looping through with an algorithm something like this (I'm just sketching the idea; don't look for correct syntax):

```
trim_lengths <- c(44, 57, 86, 86, 40, 88, 88, 41, 40, 40,
  62, 62, 54, 54, 55, 55, 63, 63, 75, 75, 100, 100)

avail_lengths <- c(120, 103, rep(100, 9), 98, rep(97, 4),
  95, rep(88, 3), 85, 65)

while(length(trim_lengths) > 0) {
  current_max <- max(trim_lengths)
  current_min <- min(trim_lengths)

  if(current_max + current_min > max(avail_lengths) {
    find smallest value in avail_lengths that's greater than current_max
    store current_max and optimal value from avail_lengths in list or vector
      to indicate the pairing/grouping
  }

  else {
    group <- c(current_max, current_min)
    current_max <- trim_lengths minux elements in group
    if <- sum(group) + current_max > max(avail_lengths) {
      store group and corresponding avail_length element in list/vector
    }

    else{
      basically, keep trying to group until solved
    }
  }
```

I already know that's not optimal, as it's checking from the "outside in" on the `trim_lengths` vector, and my hand-done pairings often end up pairing a small and mid level value into an available length that's pretty easy to see is just an inch or two longer than said pairing.

Anyway, it was an interesting problem and I wondered if there were references or obvious suggestions that would come to mind for a solution. In some of the related questions the first comment often asked, "What did you try." I really haven't... as I'm stumped at the moment. The only other thing I thought of was brute-forcing combinations randomly, storing the solution that minimizes waste.

I'd love some suggestions on solving this in a vectorized way -- some sort of matrix operation, or perhaps a linear model representation of the problem. I'll keep thinking on it  as well.

Comment: is this a knapsack problem?

Comment: It is a generalization of the knapsack problem:
the differences are that there are several knapsacks 
(the available lengths), and all objects (trim lengths)
have to be taken. You can try the same approaches as 
the knapsack: greedy algorithm, integer programming,
branch-and-bound, etc.
It can also be seen as a 1-dimensional [packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem).

Comment: Thanks for the comments -- I hadn't heard of those! Yes, very like the knapsack problem, but like @VincentZoonekynd said, multiple knapsacks and I only care about 1-dimension (length, minimizing leftover, not weight minimizing unused capacity *and* maximizing value). Thanks on the packing problem; in looking at the K-problem, I also saw the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) which also sounds related.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
 *courtesy of* http://xkcd.com/287/

(yes, this is a comment, not an answer. If only imgs could load in the little tiny comment line)

Answer (score 3):

This `multiple-knapsack` problem seemed like a fun one to try using `lpSolveAPI`, which is what I did. I used an Integer Programming approach to find the optimal solution to your trim problem.

First, here's what the solution I found looks like:

[image]

As you can see, there were 5 available pieces that weren't needed at all. (100% surplus)

**Formulation**

- Let a_1, a_2, ..., a_k be the available piece lengths.
- Let t_1, t_2, ..., t_n be the required trim lengths.
- Variables: 
  Let X_a_t be 1 if trim *t* is cut from available piece *a*, 0 otherwise

Define Surplus_i to be A_i minus the sum over j=1..n of (X_a_t * t_j)

- Objective: Minimize Sum of Surplus_i for all A's (1..k)

**Constraints**

- Set Partitioning Constraint: (in English) Every trim must be cut from some piece

  ```
    Sum over A(1..k) X_a_t = 1 for all t (1..n)
  ```

Also, all surpluses have to be >= 0 # no negatives allowed

```
A_i - sum over j in 1..k X_ai_tj * t_j  = Surplus_i (for each Ai) # definitional constraint.
```

**R Code using lpSolveAPI**

In my A-matrix (the first set of columns are Surplusses variables, and the next set are X_a_t variables.
The first set of constraints are "set cover" constraints.
The second set of constraints are "surplus" non-negativity constraints. 
Examine the trimIP.lp file to view the full formulation.

*Warning:* The code is longer than I'd have liked, but here it is:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

#Problem definition
trim.lengths <- c(44, 57, 86, 86, 40, 88, 88, 41, 40, 40, 62, 62, 54, 54, 55, 55, 63, 63, 75, 75, 100, 100)
avail.lengths <- c(120, 103, rep(100, 9), 98, rep(97, 4), 95, rep(88, 3), 85, 65)
num.trims = length(trim_lengths) #22
num.avail = length(avail.lengths) #22
a.set<-1:num.avail
t.set <- 1:num.trims

#set rownames & colnames
setRowAndColNames<- function() {  
  a.and.t<- t(outer(a.set, t.set, paste, sep="_"))
  col.names <- paste("x_", a.and.t, sep="")
  s.vars <- paste("Surplus_", a.set, sep="")
  c.names <- c(s.vars, col.names)
  r.names <- setRowNames() 
  return( list(r.names, c.names)  )
}

setRowNames <- function() {
  cover.rows<- paste("CoverTrim", t.set, sep="_") #Cover constraints
  surplus.rows <- paste("DefineSurplus", a.set, sep="_") #non-neg constraints
  r.names <- c(cover.rows, surplus.rows)
  return(r.names)
}

populate.Amatrix <- function() {  
  df <- data.frame(matrix(0, n.rows, n.cols))  #create a dataframe shell  
  for (row in 1:num.trims) {
    skip = num.avail #for the surplus variables
    cols <- seq(0, (num.trims*num.avail)-1, by=num.avail)    
    df[row, skip+cols+row] <- 1
  }
  print("Done with cover Trims Constraints")
  st.row <- num.trims+1
  end.row<- st.row+num.avail-1
  for (row in st.row:end.row) {
    surplus.column <- row - num.trims
    df[row,surplus.column] <- 1
    current.a <- surplus.column
    acols <- num.avail + ((current.a-1)*num.trims) + (1:num.trims)
    df[row,acols] <- trim.lengths

  }
  return(df)
}


defineIP <- function(lp) {
  obj.vector <- c(rep(1, num.avail), rep(0, num.avail*num.trims))
  set.objfn(lp, obj.vector ) #minimize surplusses
  set.constr.type(lp, rep("=", n.rows), 1:n.rows) 
  rhs.vector <- c(rep(1, num.avail), avail.lengths)
  set.rhs(lp, b=rhs.vector, constraints=1:n.rows) # assign rhs values   

  #Set all the columns at once
  for (col in 1:n.cols) {
    set.column(lp, col, df[ ,col])  
  }

  for (col in (num.avail+1):n.cols) {
    print(col)
    set.type(lp, col, "binary")      
  }

  #assemble it all
  dimnames(lp) <- setRowAndColNames()
  write.lp(lp, "trimIP.lp", "lp")#write it out
}


# actual problem definition
n.rows <- num.trims + num.avail
n.cols <- (num.avail+1) * num.trims  #the extra one is for surplus variables
df <- populate.Amatrix()

lptrim <- make.lp(nrow=n.rows, ncol=n.cols)
defineIP(lptrim)
lptrim
solve(lptrim)
sol <- get.variables(lptrim)
sol <- c(sol, trim.lengths)
sol.df <- data.frame(matrix(sol, nrow=24, ncol=22 , byrow=T)) #you can examine the solution data frame
```

If you want to reproduce the entire exercise, I placed the code as a github [gist](https://gist.github.com/Ram-N/6162640)

Comment: It'll take me a bit to work through that code (haven't done much matrix stuff in R), but the graphic is an awesome illustration of how it worked. I also need to double check my lengths (and data I provided), as I definitely didn't end up with five extra pieces when I did this by hand the other night! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me more like a 1-D cutting stock problem. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem
There is quite a bit out there on this topic.

Hope this helps. I just love it when somebody has a practical problem where they are doing something real and actually think about how to solve their problem rather than just blindly charge in. Hugely powerful learning opportunities... just don't get so hung up on the technical intricacies that you forget to actually do the real job too!

Comment: I can't believe how many problems there are that echo extreme similarities to just what I'm trying to do. This is probably the closest, with the exception that I have multiple length inputs vs. the paper mill example with master rolls of the same width. Don't worry, I re-worked my lengths by hand and am done with a good portion of the installation... I'd still like to see if there was a better way, especially if I order more trim for other parts of my house next year :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a genetic algorithm?

Comment: No. In my skim of [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm), I get the idea (I think; reminds me of sort of machine learning, but with a biomimetic/evolutionary component). That said, the idea is so broad, I'm not really sure what it means in terms of applying it to this problem.

Comment: That's often the case with a GA - it's a great idea, but usually quite a lot of work to mangle your problem to fit with any GA approach. A better line of attack might be one of the other local search techniques like simulated annealing or tabu search.